# Why doesn't the URL change when I click on a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a set of tabs:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Data Pribadi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Pengangkatan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Lampiran</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    tabs1
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    tabs2
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
    tabs3
</div>
```

Each tab has a unique ID. When I click on a tab with an ID of `tab1`, I expect the page's URL to change to `http://www.example.com/#tab1`. I expect a similar thing to happen for each of the other tabs. I was using this JavaScript code to that effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});
```

To the extent that you can click a tab and have the content change, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/QrLMW/1/). However, when I click on one of the links to change the tab, the URL doesn't change. Why is this, and how can I make the URL change as I expect?

Comment: can you clarify what you need, becuase you code seems to be working, check [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/QrLMW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify your code a little adding

```
    if ($(this).attr("class")!='active') {
    // all other code here
    }
```

just not to fade it when it's already opened, but everything seems to be working: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/QrLMW/1/)

Comment: he can actually because he is using selector

Comment: thanks for answering, but when clicking on the tab url is not appearing ... eg if cliked tabs 2 url : xxx.php#tabs2

Comment: try `window.location.hash` or you have to completely change your code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return false;`. That line tells jQuery to not change the URL; if you *do* want it changed, simply omit it.